# How do I print only the first page of multiple PDF documents using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, pdf

```
$files = Get-ChildItem “D:\printing\*.pdf” -Recurse 
write-host "$files"
foreach ($file in $files){
    start-process -FilePath $file.fullName -Verb Print
}
```

Here is my code which is printing all the pdf files of specified path.I am unable to find any way which allows me to print only first page of all pdf files. Any idea would be of great help.

Comment: My suggestion is to look for a command-line tool that can extract a page from a PDF as a separate file. You could temporarily extract the first page to a separate file, print that, then delete it.

Comment: So there is no way we can directly specify the page number we want to print in powershell print command?